# Binary, compiled with newer gcc compatibility

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gcc, c++

I need to compile simple c++ program that will be used in old 32 bit Linux machine. I was expecting that I can take this old machine and build everything there, but found that default GDB is too old there.

Now I'm planning to take newest 32 bit Ubuntu, build there and copy binary to old system. Can I expect some troubles while moving binary compiled in newer system to old (even possible not Ubuntu) one.

Can C++ libraries be not compatible in old and new system?

Comment: Depends on what you call "old" ;) Linking could be the point causing you trouble, if "old" enough (the 32 bits is easily fixed via an "-m32"  option if you're on x64). See : https://github.com/mapbox/cpp/issues/4 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563906/compiling-c-into-portable-linux-binaries

Comment: Did you mean gcc is too old or are you trying to compile gdb?

Comment: Compile on older OS : The executable is expected to work with a new OS. ... Compile on new, use on old usually never works : Too old glibc (libc6), too old libstdc++ !

Comment: Since GDB is old I expect GCC will be old either